# CollectionViewCell not creating

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am making a program a single view controller has two collection views. I have successfully populated the top view controller but when adding the second I am not able for it to populate correctly. this is my current code. I keep receiving a error of "Could not cast value of type 'OperationDepth.messageCollectionViewCell' (0x10a4e1e98) to 'OperationDepth.matchCollectionViewCell' (0x10a4e1c98).
(lldb) "

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

   var matchImage: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1.jpg")!,
                            UIImage(named: "image2.jpg")!,
                            UIImage(named: "image3.jpg")!,
                            UIImage(named: "image4.jpg")!,
                            UIImage(named: "image5.jpg")!,
                            UIImage(named: "image6.jpg")!]

var matches = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

 return matchImage.count       
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MatchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! matchCollectionViewCell

   let image = matchImage[indexPath.row]

   cell.matchImage.image = image

    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    return cell
} 


class MessageViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var matches = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return matches.count        
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cellId = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)  as! messageCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    // cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/256, green: 255/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66)
    //cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

    return cellId
} 
}
```

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Yes I am using storyboards @Mochi

Comment: In storyboards, try changing "cell" to a more unique identifier like "MatchCell" and "MessageCell". Do the same with your code.

Comment: @Mochi I have made the changes you requested. I am not receiving this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier MatchCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
". Also made changes to the code above

Comment: Do you have both custom cells registered in your storyboard with their respective reuse identifier "MatchCell" and "MessageCell" with their respective custom classes,  messageCollectionViewCell and matchCollectionViewCell

Comment: Also why are you using two view controllers in one view controller, you can handle two UICollectionView using a single ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to handle two UICollectionViews in a single view controller. I registered both collection views through outlets and made custom UICollectionViewCells for both cells

```
class TeamVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var gameCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var teamPlayers = [Player]()
    var teamGames = [Game]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gameCollectionView.dataSource = self
        gameCollectionView.delegate = self

        playerCollectionView.dataSource = self
        playerCollectionView.delegate = self

    }


    //MARK: Collection View Delegate Functions
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if playerCollectionView == self.collectionView {
            return teamPlayers.count
        }else {
            return teamGames.count
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView == self.playerCollectionView {
            let teamPlayer = teamPlayers[indexPath.row]

            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {
                cell.configureCell(player : teamPlayer)
                return cell
            }else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
        }else {
            let teamGame = teamGames[indexPath.row]
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TeamGameDataCell", for: indexPath) as? TeamGameDataCell {
                cell.configureCell(game: teamGame)
                return cell
            }else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
        }
    }
```